# Error #1010 (Probably an object error)

Tags: actionscript-3

When I test my movie, I'm getting this error: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. I think it's caused by child objects but I couldn't fix it. My code:

```
var wPawn1:Object = new Object();
wPawn1.mc = new WhitePawn();
addChild(wPawn1.mc);

// Black inPeace variables
wPawn1.inPeace = "a2";

var pieces:Object = new Object();

pieces.a2.man = MovieClip(wPawn1.mc);
pieces.a2.x = 70;
pieces.a2.y = 491;

wPawn1.mc.x = pieces.a2.x;
wPawn1.mc.y = pieces.a2.y;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `pieces.a2` and `pieces.mc` before you can define properties of `a2` and `mc`.

```
var pieces:Object = new Object();

pieces.a2 = blah;
pieces.mc = blah;

pieces.a2.man = MovieClip(wPawn1.mc);
pieces.a2.x = 70;
pieces.a2.y = 491;

wPawn1.mc.x = pieces.a2.x;
wPawn1.mc.y = pieces.a2.y;
```

For clarity, your error is referring to `a2` and `mc` as being undefined and having no properties.